# Can't do wireless tethering. HTC Hero with 2.2 ROM

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-hero, rom, wifi-tethering, wi-fi

Recently a friend of mine showed be his Desire HD, and it has an option on the Wireless settings section, which is something like "USB and Portable Tethering". So when it's activated, it creates a wireless network.

He also has Android 2.2 (not a custom ROM). I've searched every option in my phone, and I don't have "portable tethering" only usb.

I tried downloading an app called "Wireless Tethering", but it creates an ad-hoc and it doesn't work very good.

So, can I do something, or I have to change my ROM to another 2.2 or even 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's much you can do beyond trying other wifi tether apps.  You could also try using CyanogenMod (for the [GSM version of the Hero](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-hero-gsm), or the [CDMA version](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-hero-cdma)).